# slideshow with ffmpeg with slide transition from right to left

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, slideshow

I am looking for  experts in ffmpeg...
I need to create a short slideshow with ffmpeg in bash, for example with 3 pictures. I tried in this way:

```
/usr/bin/ffmpeg -y -framerate 1/3 -i %03d.jpg -c:v libx264 -r 25 slideshow.mp4
```

but I would like that the pictures work like a slide, from right to left.

Then, I need to insert this slideshow into a video having a transparent portion, so I tried in this way:

```
/usr/bin/ffmpeg -y -i natale14.mp4 -i slideshow.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]overlay=288:95[tl];[tl][1:v]overlay=enable='between(t\,61,70)'[out]" -map [out] natale.mp4
```

but I found some problems, as the slideshow must be seen only from 61° second to the 70° second of the original video and not for its entire duration, but the filter does not work. 
Moreover, the slideshow would stay at a lower level than the video and not above.

I hope someone can help me!

Comment: Honestly the first step to any `ffmpeg` project is to pull the source and compile the latest version. The Ubuntu version (at least, if that's what you're using?) is usually out of date in important ways. Try that first, and see if your problems go away. More often than not, they do. At time of writing the latest is 3.1.5.

Comment: Generally true, but here the command is malformed and doesn't make any sense. Show the full console output for your command, and a sample frame of the main video at the time of the overlay.

Comment: Excuse me, I use slackware with ffmpeg 3.1.1 version.

Answer (score 1):

I have already solved the second step  with a green chroma key:

```
/usr/bin/ffmpeg -y -i slideshow.mp4 -i italia_green.mp4 -filter_complex '[1:v]colorkey=0x37fa00:0.4:0.3[ckout];[0:v][ckout]overlay[out]' -map '[out]' natale.mp4
```

I do not know how to do the slide effect.
This must be the end result: [final video](http://www.sya54m.eu/video/esempio-slide.mp4)

Comment: This doesn't seem like an answer to your own question, maybe more of a comment.